# typescript enums with value and display name

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have been working on typescript and I want display the values other than enum string but the value must be numberic.

```
export enum yearofstudy {
     FirstYear,
     secondYear,
     ThirdYear
}
```

In the above code, I need the values to be 0,1,2 but display to be 1st year, 2nd year, 3rd year. How can I do that?

Comment: Where you want to display? in dropdown?

Comment: @Justcode Yes. In dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the enum into array and then I can bind it to the `select`

```
dropdownOfYear = Object.keys(yearofstudy).filter(key => !isNaN(Number(yearofstudy[key]))).map((a) => {    
  return {
    text: a,
    value: yearofstudy[a]
  }
});
```

Here I am iterating through the enum and then removing the numbers from the array as I only need values which are there, then I am returning the text and values which I can use into the dropdown.

HTML

```
 <select>
     <option *ngFor="let item of dropdownOfYear" [value]="item.value">{{item.text}}</option>
  </select>
```

Here is a demo of [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hssjhn)

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much what pipes are for in Angular. They allow you to define this in a reusable and cacheable way. Create a pipe like

```
@Pipe({name: "yearOfStudy"})
export class YearOfStudyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value: YearOfStudy): string {
    switch (value) {
      case FirstYear: return "1st Year";
      //... 
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use

```
{{ yourValue | yearOfStudy }}
```

Comment: *public transform(value: YearOfStudy): string {*  what is YearOfStudy in this

Comment: Your enum class itself